# How to automatically create a file with code in SSH?

Tags: ssh

How would I create a file in SSH with code already in it?

Something along the lines of touch filename.php >> echo "thecode here"

??

Also, any SSH tips? Looking to become more efficient.

You know, work smarter not harder.

Comment: The best ssh tip is to read the man pages for `ssh` and `ssh_config`.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "some text" > myfile.txt
```

Will result in a file named myfile.txt with "some text" in it.

If you already have a file on your local machine that you're trying to move to the remote machine, you could use scp.

```
scp /some/local/file.txt my.server.com:/some/remote/file.txt
```